# Is there anyway to create a recursive helper in Razor Generator Template

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper, razorgenerator

I have created a template using [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) . now I need in a recursive function to create a nested list of items . I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422895/mvc3-razor-recursive-function) but then all my codes became marked as errors .

```
@* Generator: Template *@


@functions
{
    public IList<Models.Category> Topics
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

@helper ShowTree(IList<Models.Category> topics)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var topic in topics)
        {
            <li>
                @topic.Title
                @if (topic.Childs.Count > 0)
                {
                    @{
                         ShowTree(topic.Childs);
                     }
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

some of irrelevant errors I got after adding the helper :

```
-Error  3 Invalid expression term ';'
Error   4 Feature 'lambda expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification
Error   13 Feature 'implicitly typed local variable' cannot be used because it is not part of the System C# language specification
Error   6 The name 'WriteLiteralTo' does not exist in the current context
```

but as I remove the helper method , all these just disappear !

did I do something wrong or creating helpers in Razor Templates is not possible ?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: @Bobson : I added errors to the question

Comment: I'm rather puzzled.  Try removing the `@{ }` around `ShowTree()`, since you're already inside a code block.

Comment: @Bobson : if I remove @{} then that line became marked as error too !

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work.

```
@helper ShowTree(IList<Models.Category> topics)
{
    if (topics != null && topics.Any()) {
    <ul>
        @foreach (var topic in topics)
        {
            <li>
                @topic.Title
                @ShowTree(topic.Childs)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
}
```

Comment: RazorGenerator templates behave differently from how MVC works, as I've learned to my annoyance.  So just because it works in an app doesn't mean it'd work here.

Comment: That said, if it's just a code syntax issue, this may be the right fix anyway.

Comment: @Bobson can you explain why the code I provided above does NOT work in RazorGenerator? Did you try it? Or did you just down vote it?

Comment: Valid point.  Just because it works in a MVC app doesn't mean it *doesn't* work in a Template.  Vote removed.

Comment: @jessegavin : thank you , but no , it dosen't . as Bobson has said it seems that RazorGenerator templates behave differently from how MVC works

Comment: Well I'll be a monkey's uncle.

Comment: The problem I ran into is that a RazorGenerator template neither inherits from the standard template, nor from the standard view.  So you can't `@Include`, and you don't have `@Html`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, since no one's provided a better answer, we gave up on using RazorGenerator templates for this exact reason.

My question is [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13035427/298754), and our answer was to set up a local MVC website on an internal server, and use that to render our templates.  It's the only suggestion I've seen yet which has worked the way I wanted things to.