# Offline template rendering similar to MVC partial views?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, template-engine

I want to refactor an existing MVC action so that it can be used offline to build email content.

The action just fetches a model by Id and hands it over to the view, where the view renders it's fields. There is a foreach loop in the view.

My first thought was to just create an html file and do string search and replace in it.

Is there any template rendering libraries I should consider instead?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035427/razorgenerator-templates-and-html

Comment: what you mean by offline? ControllerContext is not available?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I mean outside the controller. Could for instance be from a separate thread or from a SignalR endpoint. Maybe even from a windows service or a scheduled exe file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [`RazorEngine`](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The project is currently using MVC2. Would that cause conflicts with RazorEngine?

Comment: I see, you should have mentioned that as part of your question. The RazorEngine project is using the Razor engine which works with ASP.NET MVC 3.